# how run java app on background without aid of bash tools etc

Tags: java

Say you have some cli app, which calculates something for very long and outputs it into file. I want to run it as a normal app, say `java -jar ...`, get control immediately back to shell (let it be bash/... or windows terminal), while the actual java app still runs on background.

In linux I know about `&` or better `nohup java -jar ... &>/dev/null &`, I'm not asking about that. I'm asking how to get this 'nohup' behavior, in multiplatform way without using nohup etc.

I never did that, but I guess I could start some launcher jar, run yet another one somehow in detached way (no idea how) and then quit. Is it somehow attainable within single jar?

Comment: Have you tried it under Windows 10, because this OS has got also a Linux kernel.

Comment: no, as I don't want to use nohup, that's the idea. I'd like to know, if it's somehow attainable without it. I see some projects doing this, I just don't want to decompile then as take a look, as I have no idea if they do it in best way.